# How to sort an array with numbers in iphone?

Tags: iphone, sorting, numbers

I need your help. I have stored selected indexpath values in an NSMutableArray from UITableView. I have stored these values in NSString type and i want to retrieve like NSString to int datatype. But, I want to sort this array by (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13....)this way. Currently am getting by this format(0,1,10,11,12,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9..) I dont know how to sort this array? Please any one help me friends? Thanks for spending your valuable time with me and read my poor english.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let' say your mutable array is called "myArray". Then you cannot simply sort its content using string comparator but you must convert strings to decimals and use the values to sort.
So the sorting call will be, using blocks:

```
[myArray sortUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: Yuvaraj should consider storing them in the array as NSNumber instead of NSString also.

Comment: Thank you my friend. Am not very familiar in ObjectiveC. Can you explain on your answer? Please...

Comment: Check out Apple Documentation on both NSString and NSNumber. You'll figure out.

Comment: Ya sure. Thanks to all for reply. I will check out this.